# Do I need to follow hypermedia format or a schema?

Tags: rest, json, hateoas

I'm quite new to the field. So I need to clarify what would be the best method to follow in the following situation.

I'm developing a restful API using php and use json to represent resources. While I'm at this I read it's considered to be a good practice to conform with "[HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS)" (is it?). So I wanted to use something like HAL or [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/) right? What if I do my own formatting while using IANA link relation representations and let my clients know what they should expect via json-hyper schema?

What is the best method? Did I got everything messed up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HATEOAS is a somewhat controversial topic. Many people feel it's an example of overengineering and see no practical benefit to it. I believe it offers a natural and sensible approach to implementing Web APIs, with the benefits of increased decoupling between server and clients and a lower burden on client developers (see [my answer to "REST HATEOAS - How does the client know link semantics?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659542/473305)).

Having said that, to my knowledge there are still few well established conventions for Web APIs. You'll be doing your users and yourself a favour by adopting an existing standard like [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html), though:

- Experienced developers will understand your API right away without having to learn your own unique conventions.
- You'll be able to use libraries like [ROAR](https://github.com/apotonick/roar) that generate standards-compliant representations more or less automatically.
- Clients will be able to use tools like [HyperResource](http://hyperresource.com/) that consume standards-compliant APIs without additional programming.

Should you decide to define your own formats and conventions (which is still the norm for API designers, as far as I know), not only will you be burdening the world with yet another wholly non-standard API you'll be increasing your *own* burden in terms of delivering documentation and sample code to clients.

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon. That clarifies almost all the doubts I had. Just one thing left. How json [JSON Hyper-Schema](http://json-schema.org) fits into this? Is it another hypermedia format like _HAL_ or is it used to provide a schema for consumers when we came up with our own hypermedia formatting?

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but from a quick look at the website: It appears to be a hypermedia format like HAL, as it defines a standardized way of embedding hyperlinks in JSON documents. JSON _Schema_ (not Hyper-Schema) seems to be focused on latter problem, of defining classes and their properties for consumers.

Comment: Amazing :) I have mixed up those too.. haha.. Now its clear. again thanks alot Simon.